# Django Count a Self Referencing Model

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

I'm planning on creating a leaderboard of sorts on a Django project that I'm creating. I want the leaderboard to display the top 5 users for the month. One leader board will show the top 5 users with the most referrals (the Example_User model), and the other will show the users that have earned the most points from offers (the Lead model).

```
class Example_User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=False, null=True)

class Leads(models.Model):
    example_user = models.ForeignKey('Example_user')
    offer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="offer name")
    points = models.OneToOneField('Points', blank=False, null=False)
    lead_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, verbose_name="the date the lead was completed")

class Points(models.Model):
    example_user = models.ForeignKey('Example_User')
    points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False, default=0, verbose_name="points")
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="date the points were earned")
    cash_conv = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=False, verbose_name="money converted to points")
    from_offer = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True, verbose_name="points earned from offer")
    from_reward = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=False, verbose_name="points spent on reward")
```

So I'm a little stuck. For the Leads model, I initially wanted to do something like the following (see below), but I don't know what I would put for the Sum value. Passing the entire points field to Sum is troublesome, because I only want to pass Points.points.

```
Leads.objects.filter(lead_date__month=DateTime.date.month()).annotate(total_points=Sum('points')
```

And for the Example_User model, I'm having trouble because it's a self referencing field. I want to return the top 5 users with the most referrals. I'm having trouble translating that into code though. Thanks!